# How to create an new rails app from a github URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github

How do I create an new rails app from a github URL?

Answer (score 1):

fork it in github. This will create a project in your username.

Then clone it into your local machine.

Comment: How do I clone it into my local machine?

Comment: Install git on your machine. And use 'git clone http://github.com/your-username/applicationName'

Comment: I instead downloaded the project as a zip